# Auto adding needed rows for referenced cells from multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Not sure how to exactly describe or word this question. I'm making an excel spreadsheet that takes referenced cells from one sheet and organizes them into the desired format, and then from there I copy, paste, and print. The sheets have no specific amount of rows. Sometimes there's as little as 3 and as many as 50 rows. I usually have multiple sheets to print at a time too, so what I'm looking for in the referenced sheet is for it to use the amount of rows needed for sheet 1, then when that sheet is done, it adds a space or 2 and then begins sheet 2, and so on. I'm really just looking for a way to skip the copy and pasting to a separate sheet.

Thanks

Shane

Comment: Probably a good use of VBA. Try using the macro recorder to generate a macro for you that does your copy / paste method

Comment: The easiest solution is Convert the Data Range is Table or into Dynamic Named Range. Excel automatically adjust number of Rows.